# How to make jQuery Mobile list dividers fixed at top

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, mobile-application

Is there a way to make the "data-role="list-divider" fixed at the top of the page until the next letter or list divider comes up and takes its place, like in the iPhone contact app?

Here is a link to the jquery mobie list dividers demo. The list dividers dont stay at the top but rather scroll up and down with the page.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/lists/lists-divider.html

Thanks for your help in advance.

-bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out.Not sure what exactly to do.

http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/lists-divider.html

Comment: This link no longer exists :-(

Answer (score 0):

There's a great plugin which does exactly this, and gives you custom events etc. The project is [available on GitHub](http://github.com/teamdf/jquery-list/) and there's also a [showcase article](http://www.teamdf.com/web/showcasing-jquery-list-with-a-fake-iphone/147/) about it.

The plugin allows you to use any selector to define which elements are headers, so your case will look (something) like this:

```
$('ul').list({ headerSelector : '[data-role="list-divider"]' });
```

Although, you're probably better off to use a class, or element selector for best performance :-)