# is it a way to make jQuery Mobile header list dividers fixed at top?

Tags: html, list, jquery-mobile, iphone-web-app

Is there a way to make the jquery mobile List divider header be fixed at the top of the page until the next letter or list divider comes up and takes its place, like in the iPhone UITableView?

(http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-divider.html, the list dividers dont stay at the top but rather scroll up and down with the page.)

I've already search on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814088/how-to-make-jquery-mobile-list-dividers-fixed-at-top) but the link seems to be down..

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the same thing: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/experiments/scrollview/lists-divider.html ?

Comment: broken link... I think scrollview has been removed from experiments or master

Answer (score 2):

There's a great plugin which does exactly this, and gives you custom events etc. The project is [available on GitHub](http://github.com/teamdf/jquery-list) and there's also a [showcase article](http://www.teamdf.com/web/showcasing-jquery-list-with-a-fake-iphone/147/) about it.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to port this:  [stickySectionHeaders](http://polarblau.github.com/stickySectionHeaders/)